# Asterisk before the string in a regex

Tags: python, nltk

In nltk. collocations I use this `finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda *w: w not in list)`. But I do not know what does mean the asterisk here. can someone explain me what the meaning of `*w` here? Because I know that the asterisk comes after the string and not before it.

Comment: `*` has nothing to do with regexes here.

Comment: That is functional programinng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is argument unpacking :[*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs). This means it is taking all the arguments you might pass to a function.